# Monotone cubic interpolation

Tags: c#, algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation

We have implemented it using the formula from Wikipedia :

```
public class MonotoneCubicSplineInterpolation
    {
        public static double[] Calc(double[] xs, double[] ys, double[] x_interp)
        {
            var length = xs.Length;

            // Deal with length issues
            if (length != ys.Length)
            {
                IPDevLoggerWrapper.Error("Need an equal count of xs and ys");
                throw new Exception("Need an equal count of xs and ys");
            }
            if (length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (length == 1)
            {
                return new double[] {ys[0]};
            }


           // Get consecutive differences and slopes
            var delta = new double[length - 1];
            var m = new double[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                delta[i] = (ys[i + 1] - ys[i]) / (xs[i + 1] - xs[i]);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    m[i] = (delta[i - 1] + delta[i]) / 2;
                }
            }
            var toFix = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                if ((delta[i] > 0 && delta[i - 1] < 0) || (delta[i] < 0 && delta[i - 1] > 0))
                {
                    toFix.Add(i);
                }
            }
            foreach (var val in toFix)
            {
                m[val] = 0;
            }

            m[0] = delta[0];
            m[length - 1] = delta[length - 2];

            toFix.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (delta[i] == 0)
                {
                    toFix.Add(i);
                }
            }
            foreach (var val in toFix)
            {
                m[val] = 0;
                m[val + 1] = 0;
            }

            var alpha = new double[length - 1];
            var beta = new double[length - 1];
            var dist = new double[length - 1];
            var tau = new double[length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                alpha[i] = m[i] / delta[i];
                beta[i] = m[i + 1] / delta[i];
                dist[i] = Math.Pow(alpha[i], 2) + Math.Pow(beta[i], 2);
                tau[i] = 3/Math.Sqrt(dist[i]);
            }

            toFix.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dist[i] > 9)
                {
                    toFix.Add(i);
                }
            }

            foreach (var val in toFix)
            {
                m[val] = tau[val] * alpha[val] * delta[val];
                m[val + 1] = tau[val] * beta[val] * delta[val];
            }

            var y_interp = new double[x_interp.Length];
            int ind = 0;

            foreach (var x in x_interp)
            {
                int i;
                for (i = xs.Length - 2; i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    if (xs[i] <= x)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var h = xs[i + 1] - xs[i];
                var t = (x - xs[i])/h;
                var t2 = Math.Pow(t, 2);
                var t3 = Math.Pow(t, 3);
                var h00 = 2*t3 - 3*t2 + 1;
                var h10 = t3 - 2*t2 + t;
                var h01 = -2*t3 + 3*t2;
                var h11 = t3 - t2;
                y_interp[ind++] = h00*ys[i] + h10*h*m[i] + h01*ys[i + 1] + h11*h*m[i + 1];

                continue;
            }

            return y_interp;
        }
    }
```

Please comment about style, correctness and complexity.

Comment: Regarding correctness: Where are your unit tests? This is trivial to write unit tests for.

Comment: @DanielMann it is tested the results are ok. i'm talking in a more general way.

Comment: @Gilad - can you tell what is this `x_interp` and what values should this be? Thanks.

Comment: @SpaceDog if I recall correctly it is an array of points which represent how many new points you would like to have, for example when fitting into a curve..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't throw `Exception`

> ```
> throw new Exception("Need an equal count of xs and ys");
> ```

It forces client code to catch any subclass of `Exception`. In this case I would throw an `ArgumentException`.

---

The `continue` at the end of the last loop is redundant.

---

Here you're using `double.Equals`

```
if (delta[i] == 0)
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The `Equals` method should be used with caution, because two apparently
>   equivalent values can be unequal due to the differing precision of the
>   two values.

That link covers two techniques for dealing with this.

---

As far as I can tell, `toFix` can be removed. For example,

> ```
> var toFix = new List<int>();
> for (int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++)
> {
>     if ((delta[i] > 0 && delta[i - 1] < 0) || (delta[i] < 0 && delta[i - 1] > 0))
>     {
>         toFix.Add(i);
>     }
> }
> foreach (var val in toFix)
> {
>     m[val] = 0;
> }
> ```

Can be rewritten as

```
for (int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++)
{
    if ((delta[i] > 0 && delta[i - 1] < 0) || (delta[i] < 0 && delta[i - 1] > 0))
    {
        m[i] = 0;
    }
}
```